# authentication with a third party provider

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-oauth, hapi.js, rest-security

I'm developing an api server in (NodeJs/ hapi) coupled with an android application.
I'm having a problem understanding how to do login via a third party like google and facebook.

So far my strategy is:

1. authorize my app(android)
2. get the email and other data from google/facebook(android)
3. Send email and data to my server and save it in a database(server)

Next time when authentication. I'll just check the same data(from google) against the save data(my server).
I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do it, but the documentation I have read so far leave me with a head ache.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just setup a demo project using ExpressJS.
It would be interesting to have a fork for Hapi.

Check it out if want: http://git.io/RHnjBg

Comment: I'll definitely do that :)